# File contains no sections headers

Tags: centos, yum

I keep getting this error everytime i use yum :

```
yum install unison240
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit, security
Error: File contains no section headers.
file: file://///etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo, line: 12
'priority=1\n'
```

I am very new to this world (A small month) and didnt use it very much yet because i just started engineering school.

It seems as if CentOs-Base.repo had an error in it and i actually tried to create priorities.sh in order to follow this tutorial from my school : https://ensiwiki.ensimag.fr/index.php/Portail:Centos which could have done the error.

(First Section named "Depots Centos 6.5")

I dont know if it helps you.

This error happens with every use of yum. Here, I was just trying to get Unison from the package epel that i already got on my computer.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please explain what the expected result should be. The error message you provide doesn't make that clear.

Comment: @Jason D
It was just a test to test yum. What i wanted to do was to download Unison so I typed :
    **sudo yum install unison240**
And received the same message : 
    **Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit, security
    Error: File contains no section headers.
    file: file://///etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo, line: 12
    'priority=1\n'**

Comment: You may want to add that to your original post. Also include the full package name that you want.

Comment: The error indicates that you have an extra line break or corruption on line 12 of your repo file. Can you delete that and try again?

Comment: Ok, I will delete the repo file and post the result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To clarify, I meant delete the extra line break and not the repo file. But if that does not work you can try moving the repo file out and creating a new one from the website that you posted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like your `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` is broken - have missing `[CentOS-Base]` stanza. I was able to recreate the situation using:

```
# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/kzak-mytt-kz.repo 
[kzak-mutt-kz]
name=Copr repo for mutt-kz owned by kzak
baseurl=http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/kzak/mutt-kz/fedora-$releasever-$basearch/
skip_if_unavailable=True
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
# yum repolist
<works as expected>
# gedit /etc/yum.repos.d/kzak-mytt-kz.repo   # now I have removed first line
# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/kzak-mytt-kz.repo 
name=Copr repo for mutt-kz owned by kzak
baseurl=http://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/kzak/mutt-kz/fedora-$releasever-$basearch/
skip_if_unavailable=True
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: etckeeper
File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/kzak-mytt-kz.repo, line: 1
'name=Copr repo for mutt-kz owned by kzak\n'
```

So fix would be to go into `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` and fix syntax of the file.

Comment: Helped me, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The header section of one of your mirrors in that repo is missing. It is a name inside Brackets []. You can add it yourself.

In terminal, type:

```
nano /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

Then go to the line 12 and add a section header like [Name] ABOVE the line beginning with "name"

Assuming the header section is called "update", it should look like:

```
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```