# Unable to install php 5.x on CentOS , error in `remi-php56.repo`

Tags: php, linux, centos

A beginner here , trying to install / update PHP in my CentOS (virtual machine).

Existing PHP version : 5.3

Need to update to : 5.5+

I tried a lot of things, may be not enough but I am unable to reach to the conclusion.

I even tried

```
yum update
```

I got the following **error**:

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Error: File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/remi-php56.repo, line: 1
"name=Remi's PHP 5.6 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64\n"

I checked the file and this is the first line in the file

```
name=Remi's PHP 5.6 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
```

Getting the above error for all the methods I tried. Losing brains now. Pleas help! Thank you.

Comment: this is the only repo for rpm PHP 5.6 ? perhaps test other...

Comment: I am afraid this is the only repository, the other is remi-php70 but I am unsure about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to update.
Edited the repo file and added

```
[epel]
```

on first line.

Answer (score 1):

it seem to be a syntax error. Read this and proceed with example file : [syntax error repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407178/file-contains-no-sections-headers)

perhaps solve your problem

Comment: the link you provided did not help, but you did point me in the right direction. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't known where the /etc/yum.repos.d/remi-php56.repo file comes from.

```
$ rpm -ql remi-release
/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
/etc/yum.repos.d/remi-php70.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/remi-safe.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

Please use the remi-release package matching your CentOS version (it seems you are trying to use a fedora one)

You can also follow the information given by the wizard: http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/