# getting invalid syntax error while running python script in bash

Tags: python

i have a python3.6.0 script which works perfectly well on windows. but when i run it in bash i get syntax error. here is the code:

```
import itertools

lines=["Hamlet","William Shakespeare","Edited Barbara B Mowat Paul Werstine","Michael Poston Rebecca Niles","Folger Shakespeare Library","httpwwwfolgerdigitaltextsorgchapter5playHam","Created Jul 31 2015 FDT version 092","Characters Play","line 17 POLONIUS father Ophelia Laertes councillor King Claudiusthis line substituted GHOST"]
LinesMap=dict()
for line in lines:
list=[l for l in line.split(' ')]
d = dict(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(list)] * 2, fillvalue=None))
LinesMap = {**LinesMap, **d}

print(LinesMap)
```

this is the error:

```
[reza@localhost ~]$ python New\ Text\ Document.py 
File "New Text Document.py", line 16
LinesMap = {**LinesMap, **d}
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The Python code has indentation errors which will cause syntax errors on every platform. Please [edit] the question to show the actual, runnable code. (On the desktop version of this site, you can paste your code, select it with the mouse, and type ctrl-K to have it properly formatted as a code block.)

Comment: Alternatively, you can just use `LinesMap.update(d)`.

Comment: But that doesn't help with `longest_zip` which also does not exist in Python 2. The proper solution is really to upgrade to the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: @tripleee Agreed, but `izip_longest` exists. The code will not work with Python 3 then (except for some try-to-import tricks), but it might serve OP's needs. (Also, Python 2 _is_ still supported, although not recommened)

Comment: Python 2 is nominally supported until 2020, but it is quite clear that many experts and library maintainers have already abandoned it, or are planning to. By the original timetable, Python 2 was going to be end-of-lifed last year already. It's not a good use of your time to try to fight the process to migrate everyone to Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

On many Linux distros, `python` refers to Python 2, and you need to use `python3` to run a Python 3 script.

Depending on your distro, you should be able to `yum` or `apt-get` a package with Python 3, which can coexist nicely alongside Python 2, partly thanks to the decision to use different names for the executables.

In more detail, `apt-get install -y python3` (probably with `sudo` or ask your admin) should install Python 3 on Debian-based platforms (Mint, Ubuntu, what have you); and `yum install python36` should install Python 3.6 on various RPM-based platforms (Fedora, CentOS, etc, again probably with `sudo` or something equivalent).

Comment: while trying to run "yum install python36", i get the error:                                                                                                                                         "                                                                                                                   Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks

File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/CentosBase.repo, line: 1
'entOS-Base.repo\n'    "

Comment: The error message tells you how to investigate it, there's what appears to amount to a syntax error in the file it points to. This seems entirely related to your CentOS package manager's configuration, and not at all to Python.

Comment: yes! but this is the cuase why my python3.6 code does not run. because python3.6 is not installed and i can not install it using yum because of the error in the previous comment! how can i install python3.6 then?

Comment: If you really cannot figure it out, this is a separate problem which you can ask about at [unix.se]. But they will need to see the actual file which the system is complaining about, not just the error message. Also, make sure this isn't a question which has been asked before.

Comment: Quick googling gets me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407178/file-contains-no-sections-headers which is off-topic and should be closed, but hopefully allows you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
python3 New\ Text\ Document.py
```

Bash is using python 2 to run this.

Comment: python3 is not installed or enabled on my linux. what can i do?

Comment: If you want to run a Python 3 script, you need to install it. Else, you need to convert your script to Python 2, which is probably not a good use of anyone's time.

Comment: @Reza you can [install it](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/linux/) or translate the script to python2. simply replacing the incriminating line with `LinesMap.update(d)` should do the trick if this is the only issue.