# Upgrade vim to version 8 on CentOS: File contains no section headers

Tags: vim, centos7, upgrade

I tried to install the plugin YouCompleteMe for vim. YouCompleteMe requires Vim 8.1.2269+. vim on CentOS 7 is version 7.4 with patches 1-160.

I upgrade vim to version 8 followed [this post](https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-upgrade-vim-to-version-8-on-centos-7/),

```
# Add this repository:
$ curl -L https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/mcepl/vim8/repo/epel-7/mcepl-vim8-epel-7.repo -o /etc/yum.repos.d/mcepl-vim8-epel-7.repo

$ yum update vim*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks


File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mcepl-vim8-epel-7.repo, line: 2
'<!doctype html>\n'
```

It raised the error `File contains no section headers.`. This thread [centos - File contains no sections headers - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407178/file-contains-no-sections-headers) targets for `CentOS-Base.repo`. The answer doesn't solve my question.

A part of the content of `mcepl-vim8-epel-7.repo` is as followed.

```
$ head /etc/yum.repos.d/mcepl-vim8-epel-7.repo

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Not Found</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/system_static/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="/system_static/patternfly/css/patternfly.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/system_static/patternfly/css/patternfly-additions.min.css">
```

How do I upgrade vim to version 8 on CentOS 7?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File contains no sections headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407178/file-contains-no-sections-headers)

Comment: @wxz No, it doesn't. the thread targets for `CentOS-Base.repo`.