# AWS Ec2 trying to install ern stack but always says File contains no section headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum

Hi I'm just trying to install my school project to `ec2,` I pushed my server to Github, launched ec2 instance. I wacthed tutorials they almost every of them instlal with `sudo- apt-get` but currently doen't work. trying to instlal with `yum` always says this.

**File contains no section headers.**
How to i fix it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ6UN.png)

Another

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dkac.png)

Comment: So use Ubuntu ec2 instance, not Amazon Linux.

Comment: using ubuntu may can make it work and easy

Comment: okay i will try it

Comment: Amazon ami has built in packages, in my experience this is much more easy

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

- Go to /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.2.repo.
- Open the file and share line number 2.
- Most probably you have an error on this line.
- Run `yum update` first and then try to install any packages.

To understand `yum update` read this blog: https://embeddedinventor.com/yum-update-vs-yum-upgrade-differences-explained/

If you still face issues then refer to this answer : [File contains no sections headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407178/file-contains-no-sections-headers)

Comment: same I added details

Comment: Ok,

1. Go to file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.2.repo.

2. Open the file and share line number 2.

3. Most probably you have an error on this line.

Comment: Or you can simply remove that file from that place and have a backup at another place. Then finally run your yum commands and it should work fine.